# Exception skipped Typescript Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to perform a validation and if no exception is thrown, then perform an action. The problem is that the code is async, so the "CompletePlanConfirm()" method is always run, but must be skipped if exception occurs. FirstCheck and secondCheck return Observable. is there a way to accomplish this?

```
completePlan() {
    try {
        this.validatePlan();
        this.completePlanConfirm();
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}

validatePlan() {
    this.planService.FirstCheck(this.plan.id).subscribe(
        data => {
            if (!data.result) {
                throw Error('Error 1')
            }
        });
    this.planService.SecondCheck(this.plan.id).subscribe(
        data => {
            if (!data.result) {
                throw Error('Error 2')
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: How is `completePlan` supposed to treat errors from `validatePlan`? `catch(error) { throw error }` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sample code is a simplification of real one. I currently have a Global error handler for treating errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `async` and `await` and make your plan checks resolve promises.  This makes your `completePlan` function a lot cleaner.

```
async completePlan() {
    try {
        const response1 = await this.checkFirstPlan();
        const response2 = await this.checkSecondPlan();
        
        this.completePlanConfirm();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    }
}

checkFirstPlan(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.planService.FirstCheck(this.plan.id).subscribe((data: any) => {
            if (!data.result) {
                throw new Error('Error 1')
            }
            resolve(data);
        }, (error: any) => {
          throw new Error(msg);
        }, () => { });
      });    
}

checkSecondPlan(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.planService.SecondCheck(this.plan.id).subscribe((data: any) => {
            if (!data.result) {
                throw new Error('Error 2')
            }
            resolve(data);
        }, (error: any) => {
          throw new Error(msg);
        }, () => { });
      });    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use async / await to make your code synchronous.

Firstly change your `validatePlan` function so it retuns an observable (and some changes to avoid nested subscription :

```js
validatePlan() {
  return this.planService.FirstCheck(this.plan.id).pipe(
    map(data => {
      if(!data.result) {
      throw Error('Error 1')
      }
    }),
    switchMap(() => this.planService.SecondCheck(this.plan.id))
  ).pipe(
     map(data => {
      if(!data.result) {
      throw Error('Error 1')
      }
    }),
  )
}
```

Then make `completePlan` an async function and place the await keyword before the `validatePlan` function (it needs to be changed into a Promise with `.toPromise()`

```
async completePlan() {

try {

  await this.validatePlan().toPromise();
  this.completePlanConfirm();
} catch (error) {
  throw error
}
```

This way the execution of the function will be synchronous and will wait for `validatePlan` before going further (so if an error is thrown it'll never try to confirm the plan)

Comment: Thanks for your time, It seems pretty solid solution. Nevertheless, I went with @xinthose 's solution for simplicity.